# Middleware when running Artisan console request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want a custom piece of middleware to run whenever I run an artisan command. I need to set a few environment variables to be used in the app configuration before the actual command executes but Im not able to find any documentation on the Artisan request lifecycle.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: You also use AppServiceProvider.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way, not sure if the correct one, but works. Just open up the Kernel class and override the bootstrap method. Laravel 5.3, have not tested on other versions, but should work similiary.

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        // Your commands here
    ];

    public function bootstrap()
    {
        // Don't forget to call parent bootstrap
        parent::bootstrap();

        // Do your own bootstrapping stuff here
    }

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // Add cron schedules here, if needed
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is two years old but what custom code do you write here to include a selected middelware?

Comment: @Dubby my answer is 6 days old, not two years :) Anyway, you cannot include a regular middleware there, but you can add your custom code to execute for every console script call.